# Give priority to the (software) time stamping thread in e1000e net driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, ethernet, nic, thread-priority, timestamping

I am new to linux programming. I have an intel NIC with e1000e driver. I am working on precise time stamping of packets being captured from a network. An interrupt is generated at every packet reception. Thus an interrupt handler registered by the driver queues the captured packets and timestamps it. My question is if want to use RT Linux how can I increase the priority of the time stamping thread. 
Is this possible?

Comment: *"An interrupt is generated at every packet reception."*  -- That is not true for most NICs because there are preallocated (e.g. ring) buffers for receiving frames at high rates.  Also most Linux drivers for NICs use NAPI and can exit interrupt RX mode and switch to polled mode to reduce receive overhead.

Comment: Yes you are right, there are two modes; one is an interrupt mode and the other is a poll mode when the traffic rate is very high. For my particular case I set the interrupt throttle rate to a certain value which is good enough for my measurements.